How to deserialize a DateOnly from a JSON ISO8601 datetime with timezone?
I just wonder why the DateOnly parsing tolerates a time in the ISO8601 representation, but gives an exception when there is the timezone offset (or the Z, as UTC).
var d1 = DateOnly.Parse("2024-09-13T12:00:00.000");
var d1 = DateOnly.Parse("2024-09-13T12:00:00.000+02:00");  //throws
var d1 = DateOnly.Parse("2024-09-13T12:00:00.000Z");       //throws

I really don't see the sense of that. It should be to ignore everything after the "T": isn't it?
My actual problem is about the JSON deserialization, from what is coming from the browser to the POCO model. I see only these solutions (and none makes me happy):

trim the string on the browser side, right before it's posted;

use a DateTime instead of a DateOnly;

use a string instead of a DateOnly.


Is there any better workaround?

I would imagine that it's to avoid someone thinking that it would adjust the date according to the time zone information.

@MatthewWatson I could agree with you, but how to solve the JSON problem?

The question is: Would you WANT it to change the date depending on the time zone information? If so, then you can just parse to DateTime and use DateOnly.FromDateTime().

By the way, you should change the title of your question to the actual question you're asking. Why it throws isn't relevant - how to deal with it is the relevant question.

Fourth alternative, write your own JsonConverter for DateOnly that first strips out the timezone information (or of you want to use ut, that first parses it as DateTime and then converts that to DateOnly)

@Karl-JohanSjögren that's a good point, although I'd hope for something already available (i.e. an attribute or so)

@MatthewWatson title changed

@MatthewWatson Annoyingly ParseExact doesn't work either https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBDsJ8 even though it works with just a time spec. The internal parsing code uses a flags restriction https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/59e8bbcf83b664c3de6cfa553d9bbfad76578765/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/DateOnly.cs#L277 preventing any value other than a UTC date value.

how to solve the JSON problem? -- what JSON serializer are you using?  Json.NET?  System.Text.Json?  Something else?  Please [edit] your question to share a JSON sample + [mcve] showing how you are trying to deserialize it.  Thanks!

Related: this answer by Matt Johnson-Pint to How can I write an ISO 8601 date with a timezone but no time component: Officially, the ISO 8601 spec does not allow for a date with a time zone unless a time is provided. Thus, if you wish to remain ISO 8601 compliant, you cannot provide additional information for date-only values than year, month, and day (without resorting to time intervals - mentioned further below)...

@dbc to me, the reason for the question was about the parsing. That is, why the DateOnly parser couldn't drop the time-zone like it does for the time part. The supposed reason of "someone could think the TZ will round the date" could be true, but seems very weak. The deserialization is the goal, but to me looks secondary. To be forced to write a converter (or similar workarounds) for a so basic problem seems a total nonsense. However, I respect all of your viewpoints. Hence, I followed the suggestion to change the title of the post.
